# How to plot and analyze multi variable SVM regression in R

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, svm

I am new to R and having some trouble with plotting svm models. 
1)How can we plot and analyze mulit variable SVM regression model results.

```
library(e1071)
set.seed(3)
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*5), nrow=100))
train=data[1:70,]
test=data[71:100,]
fit = svm(X1 ~ ., data=train)
summary(fit)
pred=predict(fit,test)
```

2) Assume one of the variable (eg: X2) contains qualitative data (eg: high,low and medium) instead of quantitative data, then how should we plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **you cannot**. There is no way to visualize an object that is more than 3-dimensional.

What you can do is to deal with some simplification, approximation, etc. you often visualize characteristic of the model and not the model itself. For example one might plot:

- relation between error metric (like R2) vs. some hyperparameter (regularization strength, kernel width, size of the training sets etc.)
- find two most significant dimensions of the dataset and plot your model as 3d surface on top of these two dimensions only
- if your dimensionality is not very high you can do pairplots, so visualize each pair of dimensions -> as it requires `d(d-1)/2` plots, thus for d=5 it is just 10 plots.
- many other characteristic important **from the perspective of your experiment**